# Is it possible to open incomplete video-file for playback using directshow?

Tags: directshow, playback

Is it possible to open incomplete video-files for playback using directshow?
The current solution first downloads the video file (.avi-container, can be h.264, mpeg2, mpeg4) and then starts playback. This can of course be a rather lengty operation.

The downloader fetches the videofile in chunks from a database so in theory it should be possible to open the file during download.

Is it possible to create a Directshow graph that can start the playback during download even if the file is incomplete when playback starts?

The software is written in C++ both server/client.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

at the least http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player#cite_note-12 will probably do it...

As far as I'm aware, though, you should be able to start the graph as soon as the file exists...as long as it doesn't reach the end during playback while the file hasn't been written yet.

Or are you looking for some filter that will "wait patiently" before replaying?